# Verify that Expression is a member selection

Tags: c#

I have:

```
TMember ResolveMember<T, TMember>(T instance, Expression<Func<T, TMember>> expression) {
  ...
```

I can call this with: `

```
  record Employee(string Name, int Age);
  var dave = new Employee("Dave", 30);
  var name = ResolveMember(dave, x => x.Name);
```

How can I guarantee that `expression` is a member resolver so that ie `ResolveMember(dave, x => "bla")` does not work ?

Is it correct that this check is not possible in compile time ?

I tried to add:

```
  if (expression.Body is not MemberExpression) throw new Exception();
```

which will throw for the above case but *not* for:

```
  var john = dave with { Name = "John" };
  var name = ResolveMember(dave, x => john.Name);
```

I can manually check for the parameter names but is there a general better way to cover this  ? Ideally I would also like to accept ie `x => x.y.z`

Comment: "Is it correct that this check is not possible in compile time ?" yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between `x => john.Name` and `x => x.Name` is that the body of the former does not have a `ParameterExpression`. You don't actually need to check for the parameter *names*, just check for instances of `ParameterExpression` in the tree, recursively.

You can do something like this:

```
static bool IsExpressionValid(Expression expr)
{
    if (expr is ParameterExpression) // this is to handle "x => x" being invalid
    {
        return false;
    }
    return IsExpressionValidImpl(expr);
}

static bool IsExpressionValidImpl(Expression expr)
{
    if (expr is ParameterExpression)
    {
        return true;
    }
    if (expr is MemberExpression memberExpr)
    {
        return IsExpressionValidImpl(memberExpr.Expression);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Some tests:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string s = "";
    // true
    Console.WriteLine(IsLambdaValid((string x) => x.Length));
    // false, not a parameter
    Console.WriteLine(IsLambdaValid((string x) => s.Length));
    // false, not a member access
    Console.WriteLine(IsLambdaValid((string x) => x));
    // true, works for nested member access too
    Console.WriteLine(IsLambdaValid((Exception x) => x.Message.Length));
}

static bool IsLambdaValid<T, U>(Expression<Func<T, U>> lambda)
{
    return IsExpressionValid(lambda.Body);
}
```

Comment: In one function: `static bool IsExpressionValid(Expression expr, bool first=true) { if (expr is ParameterExpression) return !first; return expr is MemberExpression memberExpr && memberExpr.Expression is object && IsExpressionValid(memberExpr.Expression, false); }
`